# Switch recipient account in Web3Py using Metamask

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, metamask, web3py

I want to dynamically change the recipient account `web3.eth.accounts[0]` in Web3py according to the currently selected Ethereum account in Metamask. How can I do that? Now, I set the sender and recipient on my Web3Py code like this but as soon as I change the current account, the address of the sender/receiver is still the same.

```
address = web3.eth.accounts[1] // recipient
address2 = web3.eth.accounts[0] // sender
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do that?

You cannot.

Web3.py and MetaMask cannot communicate. MetaMask cannot pass its private key to web3.py, as this is on purpose of the security (otherwise any software could steal your key). [Please read here how to manage local private keys with Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Can I do that in Web3JS?

Comment: Yes, web3.js can do it, but *only* if you run your application on a web page. Node.js is equivalent to Python run-time and cannot access MetaMask.

Comment: This is noted. I am running my app on a web page, so I'll try this one. Thank you, Mikko!